# How do I get my regexextract forumula to work in google sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to use regexextract on a list of cells in google sheets. I've tested the regular expression and it works for the string I'm trying to extract, but when I use it in google sheets, it seems to be splitting the output into a few different columns.

I tried using this formula:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(C107,"[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+X[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+X[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+")`

and was expecting this string:

WASHER SS 3.2X6X0.5 A4

to output:

3.2X6X0.5

But instead I was getting:
3. [Blank column] 0.

Split into 3 cells. Hope I've explained this problem clearly enough, and thanks in advance for reading this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

=REGEXEXTRACT(C107,".+ (\d.+) ")

Comment: You can see more [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt)

Comment: Sorry, I redacted some stuff that's part of my company's naming convention, but it had a serial number behind it in brackets. The test data was actually something like: 

WASHER SS BRB 3.2X6.5X0.5 A4 (701402)

And your formula would output: 
3.2X6.5X0.5 A4

Instead of just the 3 numbers with the X between them like I wanted. Could you suggest how to get the correct regex to get just that bit?

Comment: You can try with =REGEXEXTRACT(C107,".+ (\d.+?) ")

Comment: argh I'm so sorry! This worked for that cell but some others have it like "WASHER BRB 6.7X14X1.5" which this regex did not work for. Basically I'm trying to extract "(Float/integer)X(Float/integer)X(Float/integer)" from the cells. Thanks so much for you help, and so sorry I did not state my problem clearly enough.

Comment: What about this? `=REGEXEXTRACT(C107,"([\d\.]+X[\d\.]+X[\d\.]+)")`

Comment: That worked, marked it as solved from this answer. Thank you!